# select row from 2 table where row x ( in table a) equal some value

Tags: sql

I have two table

Table `login`

```
account_id    |    name
========================
12345         |    thuong1
12346         |    thuong2
12347         |    thuong3
```

Table `char`

```
account_id    |    char
========================
12345         |    name1
12345         |    name2
12345         |    name3
12345         |    name4
```

I want to select ...

`SQL 1`

`SELECT account_id FORM char WHERE char='name1'`

I will have result

`12345`

`SQL 2`

`SELECT login.account_id, login.name, char.char WHERE login.account_id=char .account_id GROUP BY  login.account_id , login.name, char.account_id, char.char HAVING login.account_id = 12345`

Result

```
account_id | name    | char  
12345      | thuong1 | name1  
12345      | thuong1 | name2  
12345      | thuong1 | name3
```

How i select it with 1 one sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.account_ID,
        a.name, 
        b.char
FROM    login a
        INNER JOIN char b
            ON a.account_ID = b.account_ID
WHERE   a.name='thuong1'
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80c93/4)